# CrossThreadMessageException

Tags: vb.net, exception, multithreading

I've been trying to lower the load time on the main window my application uses(10k+ lines of code) and am trying to integrate threading into one method of the program.  I'm trying to split the display method where it sets all the data on the form, it's over 1000 lines long so splitting it up would reduce load time of the form.

I'm still new to threading but since nothing is actually getting changed, i'm just running the display code alongside each other I figured threading would be the best bet.  There is one issue with this though.  They all use a similar method to determine if the component on the form should be visible/enabled depending on the account.

This is where I'm getting my exception at, when it tries to set the text of the component on the form.  I've read up on this and you cannot update an item in a thread from another thread but I haven't been able to find a solution or help online.  What possible solutions could there be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use invoke function `Obj.Invoke(Delegate)`.

Comment: HTML cannot be used to style your posts. Please use markdown instead. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either the `Invoke` method or the `BeginInvoke` method of the control or form.  All `Control` objects have these methods and, since `Form` inherits from `Control`, all forms have these methods too.  Both of these methods will call a given delegate from the UI thread.  If the UI thread is busy, however, it won't execute the delegate until the thread is free.  If you call `Invoke`, your worker thread will be blocked (hung) until the UI thread finishes executing the delegate.  If, however, you call `BeginInvoke`, the worker thread will continue on and won't wait for the UI thread to execute the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Delegates are a little tricky and am just looking for some clarification. Currently, the method that is causing me issues gets called around 50 separate times for all the 50 components on the form. Here is my delegate code that isn't currently working:   Public Delegate Sub testDisplayDel(ByVal sControlName As String, ByVal sUIName As String, ByRef IsEnabled As Boolean, ByRef IsActive As Boolean, ByVal frmctrl As String)

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. Different than normal. 'Dim del As testDisplayDel 'del = New testDisplayDel(AddressOf getControlToDisplay) del.Invoke("cmdPriName", sUIName, bEnable, bContinue, "fraName") however, when I try to debug to see if it's working, the debugger freezes every time and the delegate variable gets an error such as: Method could not be loaded or something of the sort. What am i missing?

Comment: You don't want to call `Invoke` on the delegate (that just calls the method to which the delegate object points).  What you want to do is call the `Invoke` method of the control or form and pass your delegate to it.